# PTB rnn model one PTBModel object instead of three

Tags: tensorflow

in the PTB rnn model, three PTBModel objects are created, namely m, mvalid and mtest:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as session:
initializer = tf.random_uniform_initializer(-config.init_scale,
                                            config.init_scale)
with tf.variable_scope("model", reuse=None, initializer=initializer):
  **m** = PTBModel(is_training=True, config=config)
with tf.variable_scope("model", reuse=True, initializer=initializer):
  **mvalid** = PTBModel(is_training=False, config=config)
  **mtest** = PTBModel(is_training=False, config=eval_config)
```

my questions are:

- do all these three objects live in the same graph? (It looks like they all live under the default graph.)
- do these three objects share the same placeholders, e.g., _input_data? Or is it the case that different sets of placeholders are created with each PTBModel object, so that for example there are three _input_data placeholders within the same graph (one _input_data used for feeding training data, another for validation and yet another for testing)?
- suppose I only create one PTBModel object, would it be possible to reuse  the _input_data placeholder used for training and change its shape and use it for testing as well (where the 1st dimension, num_steps, is set to 1 at test time)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, these three objects live in the same graph.

The placeholders are different and you need to use the correct one if you want to evaluate particular part of the graph.

It would in theory be possible but it is not as trivial. E.g. you could have a training graph unrolled for 20 steps but use only a subset of the steps for evaluation. The other possibility might be to use [dynamic_rnn](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py#L332) functionality.

In general, building a few copies of the graph is not very expensive and it might not be worth spending a lot of time on optimizing the number of allocated nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answers, that helped a lot. But still, I can't quite get why you cant use None for num_steps in the _input_data placeholder, if None can be used for batch_size in the same place holder? I could see this would be problematic with mini-batched training where sequences in a mini-batch could  have different lengths; If we assume a mini-batch size of 1, would feeding a different num_step value for each input work at all?

Comment: The difference between batch_size and num_steps is that different values for num_steps would cause executing different number of nodes in the graph.

Changing batch size doesn't make the graph any different except for the shape of the operations. That's why setting None makes sense if we want to support multiple values. If you change the number of steps, the execution graph is very different. I.e. you run different number of LSTM steps.